# Android how to reset rating bar without calling setOnRatingBarChangeListener?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am playing some tone using listview.

I want to change a rating bar value using `setOnRatingBarChangeListener`.

[image]
[image]

```
changeRatingPlayer
                .setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                            float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        setToneRating();
                    }
                });
```

Also I want to reset rating bar after the user clicks on some other item of the list.
But when I click on a item of the list and using `changeRatingPlayer.setRating(0);` I reset the rating bar, but in the meantime `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` is called again, but I don't want this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fromUser` parameter to determine if the rating was changed by the user or if it was changed by your code.